# How does voxer build your list of contacts?

Tags: applications

I use [Voxer](http://voxer.com/) on my tablet as a Push-to-talk application. On my tablet I don't have list of my phone contacts. Also I didn't give Voxer the permission to browse my gmail contact list.

But something weird is happening, it lists some people I've not been in contact for ages, I don't have their phone number and I know nothing about them for ages. So, how is Voxer building my list of contacts?